# Serialize/Deserialize a byte array using Json in c++

Tags: c++, json

I'm working with Json::Value and I need to Serialize/Deserialize a byte array.

How can I convert a byte array into Json object in c++? and also the opposite way

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a C++ library for JSON? 
The [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) project calls its types `Json::Value` so you may be using that. In **jsoncpp** values are serialized as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) strings which are essentially byte arrays.

You can use `Json::FastWriter` to serialize:

```
Json::FastWriter fastWritter;
std::string serialized = fastWritter.write(value);    
serialized.c_str(); // this is the raw byte array (null terminated).
```

And `Json::Reader` to deserialize:

```
Json::Reader reader;
Json::Value value;
reader.parse(serializedString, value);
```

Comment: Hi,
I get Json::Value object as an input
How can I use this?

Comment: @YaaraBen-Or, it rather depends what you want to do with it. You can check its type, get its value and index into it (if it's an object or an array).